# how can I specify a "literal" table succinctly in a CTE?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, literals

In MS SQL Server 2008 and newer, it's possible to specify a "literal" table using `values` as a subquery:

```
select * from (
  values (1,2),
         (3,4)
  ) as foo(bar,baz)
```

However, I haven't figured out a reasonable way to specify this in a `with` clause (CTE).

I was hoping the following would work, because it works just fine in the ever-programmer-friendly PostgreSQL… but it gives a syntax error with SQL Server:

```
with foo(bar,baz) as (
  values (1,2),
         (3,4)
  )
select * from foo;
```

This alternate form *does work* but seems excessively redundant and error-prone:

```
with foo as (
  select * from (
  values (1,2),
         (3,4)
  ) as foo(bar, baz)
)
select * from foo;
```

Is there a more succinct way to specify a literal table in a CTE, in SQL server?

Comment: No there isn't a nice way in a CTE. That unnecessary SELECT annoys me to!

Comment: That's pretty much it and pretty standard across all RDBMS's. Seems like folks are always wanting more succinctness in SQL, but it's a very verbose language where, often times, being more explicit yields better results.

Comment: True enough. I guess I'm spoiled by PostgreSQL which actually tries to make obvious stuff like this easy. :-/

Comment: @JNevill: the example for Postgres **is** standard SQL, so this request is not about "wanting" more, but about following the standard

Answer (score 0):

```
with foo as (select 1 as bar, 2 as baz 
             union all 
             select 3, 4) 
select * from foo;
```

Comment: That is the Oracle way of doing it, and I would not describe it as "more succinct" :(

Comment: The "Oracle" way would require "select 1 as bar, 2 as baz from dual".

Comment: That's true, Oracle is even *less* succinct :-P